# How to create Palindrome check in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I wrote a palindrome checker in JavaScript, but I don't know how to use it in Vue. What I want is something like this:

When I enter a string, it will say either "Yes" or "No" with its color properties and its values.

Comment: whats not working?

Comment: please share your package.json

Comment: Your project is hosted [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-payne-pip71) please add it to your question in order to allow others to debug, i tried to help but without success because i'm not familiar with class component

Comment: Hi @BoussadjraBrahim thank you so much. I solved most of the parts but some of the parts are still missing. Will try my best. And will post the link. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your `palindrome()` function from the class:

1. Create a [data prop](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html#data) to hold the user input (e.g., named `input`), and bind `<v-text-field>` `v-model` to it.
2. Create a [computed prop](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html#computed-properties) (e.g., named `isPalindrome`) that returns whether `input` is a palindrome, using the function you noted in question.
3. Use a [style binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) to apply a CSS `color` based on `isPalindrome`.
4. Use [string interpolation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text) to display whether the user input is a palindrome, based on `isPalindrome`.

```html
<template>
  <v-row align="center">
    <v-text-field label="Palindrome" v-model="input" 1️⃣ />
    <span :style="{ color: isPalindrome ? 'green' : 'red' }" 3️⃣>
      {{ isPalindrome ? 'Yes' : 'No' }} 4️⃣
    </span>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

function palindrome(str: String) { /*...*/ }

@Component
export default class Palindrome extends Vue {
  input = '' // 1️⃣

  get isPalindrome() { // 2️⃣
    return this.input && palindrome(this.input)
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: Edit Palindrome Challenge]